# Curious about hide().after("") in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

I have some code [at here](http://jsfiddle.net/Marslo/QvYSj/5/):

#### html:

```
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>click me</button>
</body>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide().after('<p>hello world</p>');
  });
});
```

Actually, I've using `JQuery 2.0.2` also.

---

In my understanding, When I click the button **click me**, `"<p>This is paragraph<p>"` will be ***replaced*** by `<p>hello world</p>`.

The first click is successful. However, many `hello world` with **the growth rate of progression** show after the first `hello world` shown. For example:

[image: hello world]

---

I've checked the source code by firebug, and find it is:

```
<p style="display: none;">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p style="display: none;">hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<button>click me</button>
```

Why the first `<p>hello world</p>` wasn't be replaced by the new one?

Doesn't it suppose to show one p tag only?

Comment: What makes you think anything would be replaced? When I see methods called `hide` and `after`, I think that something is getting hidden and that something is getting put after something, not that something is replaced.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M6QTc/1/

Comment: use `$("p").replaceWith('<p>hello world</p>');` see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M6QTc/2/

Comment: Hi @hobbs, thanks for your answer. The reason of I think it's "replaced" is because, the first time, I click the button, `This is paragraph` is gone, and `hello world` shows. So, I think that might be kind of **replace**.

Comment: Hi @ArunPJohny, thank you, that's very helpful. I just want to know why `hide().after()` cannot replace like the first click.

Comment: Hi @hobbs, I know what happened finally! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's cause you're creating paragraphs

`<p>hello world</p>`

and on every click the `$('p')` is a collection of all `p` elements on your page.
  The more paragraphs you have... more appends. [live demo - issue example](http://jsfiddle.net/QvYSj/7/)

An element, even if set to `display:none` using `.hide()`, is still present in your document..

---

What you're up to is probably one of the following:

```
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").html('hello world');
  });
```

```
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").text('hello world');
  });
```

```
  $("button").click(function(){
      $("p").replaceWith('<p>hello world</p>');
  });
```

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").after('<p>Hello world</p>').remove();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I'm understood. The reason is: `after('<p>hello world</p>')`: this sentence will be added **after** every <p></p> tag, including those p tags who carry with `style="display: none;"`

Comment: By the way, your live demo perfect!!! I can figure out all by your demo. :) Marry Christmas!!

Answer (score 1):

If only you want to change the text you an do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").html('hello world');
  });
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QvYSj/6/)**

Comment: Yes, `html()` is the way to "replace". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is nothing surprising that is happening here. Actaully that is what should happen, since you are adding `<p>` tag after hiding the first `<p>` `<p>This is paragraph<p>`.

So your first click ends up having two `<p>` tag in the DOM and further clicks, adding more `<p>` tags. `hide()` does not removes the elements form the DOM; it just changes its display property. You can use `replaceWith()` or `remove()` to remove the first  `<p>`, if you want this to work,  as you needed.

```
  $("p").after('<p>hello world</p>').remove();  //remove the selected `<p>` tag after `<p>is appended.</p>`
```

or

```
 $("p").replaceWith('<p>hello world</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

`after('<element/>')` means generate an element and insert it after the selected element(s), you are generating and inserting an element after all the selected `p` element(s), on the first click you are adding 1 element, on the second click 2 elements and so on, because after each click there are more than one `p` elements. `after` doesn't replace anything.

Answer (score -1):

It happens because you adding new p element after each p tag in document (even after hidden).